# Class in parameter of function (Arduino) does not compile

Tags: class, parameters, compiler-errors, arduino

I am trying to create a simple class in C++, but I keep getting the compilation errors:

```
main:2: error: variable or field 'doSomething' declared void
main:2: error: 'person' was not declared in this scope
```

main:

```
class person {
  public:
    int a;
};

void doSomething(person joe) {
  return;
}
```

main() and stuff would go here, but even if I include main(){}, the errors still occur. I also tried adding 2 closed parentheses after joe, but then that creates the error:

```
main: In function 'void doSomething(person (*)())':
main:8: error: request for member 'a' in 'joe', which is of non-class type 'person (*)()'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. (I hope this isn't something really stupid I'm missing, because I've been researching for hours).

Edit: I found out this is an Arduino-specific error. [This post](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,41848.0.html) answers it.

Comment: Do you also have a function in your code called `person()` ?

Comment: Your code compiles correctly, so there must be something else http://ideone.com/QpdPka

Comment: No, I do not have any other functions in this code. This is the only thing I have in it.

Comment: @RandomPerson323: Glad you found a fix. May I suggest that you answer your own question with what the fix involves? External links are not guaranteed to "stay alive" and if that forum post disappears then this Q/A thread becomes useless. Please post the answer to make it solid.

Comment: @PaulSasik Thank you for the advice, just what do mean by posing the answer to make it solid? I posted it below at the same time I edited the main post. (Actually, thinking about itt, there might have been a day or two delay or something).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out after reading [this post](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,41848.0.html) that a way to work around this is:

```
typedef struct person{
public:
    int a;
};

void doSomething(void *ptr)
{  
    person *x;
    joe = (person *)ptr;
    joe->a = 3; //To set a to 3
    //Everything else is normal, except changing any value of person uses "->" rather than "."

    return;
}

main()
{
    person larry;
    doSomething(&larry);
}
```

So essentially it is:

-Change `class` to `typedef struct`

-in the parameter, replace newtype with `void *something`

-add `person *x;` and `x = (person *)ptr;` to the beginning of the function

-whenever accessing type property, use `->` rather than `.`

Comment: this seems like a huge mess to work around what must be a buggy IDE/Compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a expert but when I try to do what you want to do, I do it this way:

```
//create an instance of my class
MyAwesomeClass myObject;

void myFunction(MyAwesomeClass& object){
    //do what you want here using "object"
    object.doSomething();
    object.doSomethingElse();
}

void setup() {
    //setup stuff here
    myObject.init();
}

void loop() {
    //call myFunction this way
    myFunction(myObject);
}
```

As I said, I'm not a C++ expert but it does the job.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, you have an invalid syntax error somewhere in the declarations above "class person...". Can you copy and paste the whole file?

Comment: This is the whole file, but I found out what was wrong, now that I know it is arduino specific.